# how to check if a <div> element was added to the page - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'd like to use the [dotdotdot plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) - now, what i wouldn't like is to create all the links individually: `$("#wrapper").dotdotdot()` . i'd rather like to be able and listen for divs with the class 'textoverflow_dotdotdot' and then add the link automatically.

something like this:

```
$(document).on('DIV WAS ADDED','.textoverflow_dotdotdot', function(){
     $(this).dotdotdot();
}
```

any ideas?

INFO: i'm using jquery 1.7.2

Comment: jQuery 'live' for the resuce... It's the perfect case you use it. Check out: http://api.jquery.com/live/ and here you have a code sample  for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element

Comment: @IdoGreen: I'd check out the depreciation warning on `.live()`.

Comment: @IdoGreen live was replaced by on in my version of jquery - i already had that figured out. now my problem is the event, the user doesn't click or do anything - my page uses a lot of ajax loads and i wouldn't want to call the dotdotdot() individually every time a page was loaded - if there was a smart way to listen globally for the creation of a div with my identifier class:'textoverflow_dotdotdot' i'd really appreciate that

Comment: Only one I can think of is using DOMNodeInserted, but that's highly discouraged :S http://jsfiddle.net/ZPEbW/

Comment: Why dont you use `.dotdotdot()` on ajax success ?

Comment: @JosephMarikle i know this one, but it doesn't fire, when i load content dynamically that has my class somewhere down the tree as its offspring

Comment: @Jashwant that's a good idea! but still it's not the perfect solution, right? lets think of the users with their old pcs, when i'm having a lot of ajax loads and i'm calling the function even though there is no element on the page that needs it - also i'm having an ajax load every 3 seconds to update my notification box, already truncated text then would get the .dotdotdot over and over - wouldn't that be a waste of cpu?

Comment: Just add it to the elements that need it :). e.g. `$('.dotters').dotdotdot()` and on ajax success, do `addClass('dotters') and then use the `update` event of `dotdotdot`

Comment: @Jashwant sorry, i just edited my comment: also i'm having an ajax load every 3 seconds to update my notification box, already truncated text then would get the .dotdotdot over and over...

Comment: Just use the `update` event. I can clear further things, if you can share the code (or a part of it) on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Jashwant i didn't think of that, i'll do it this way

Comment: @IdoGreen, as `Blender` stated, `live()` has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. Also, for anyone using jQuery 1.6 and earlier use `delegate()` instead of `live()`. I believe the reason is mainly that `live()` exhibited memory issues. If you happen to use version 1.3 and earlier use `bind()`. bind() was added in 1.0, `live()` in 1.3, `delegate()` in 1.4.2 and `on()` in 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).bind('ajaxSuccess', function(){
        $('.textoverflow_dotdotdot').removeClass('textoverflow_dotdotdot').addClass('dotters').change();

})

$(document).on('change','.dotters',function(){
           $(this).dotdotdot();
});
```

credits go to Jashwant ;-)