# Generate new table row and capture click of that row JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to do the following,

I have a table within the table I have an input with a button when the button is clicked a new row is added, I then wish to capture any click upon a new row element.

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td><input type="textbox" class="mytb"/></td>
    <td><button id="addButton">Add New Row</button></td>     
</tr>
</table>​

$(document).ready(function(){

// generate new row
$('#addButton').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();                 
  var newRow = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="newtb"/></td></tr>';
  $('#mytable').append(newRow);        
});

// capture click of new row?
$('.newtb').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  
    alert('clicked');
});
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/suF7b/1/)

I am stuck in that the new row is created but the click event is not captured.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful, but could someone please explain why this is happening as I am really stuck and want to increase my JavaScript knowledge.

Comment: I think you have similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '.newtb', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  
    alert('clicked');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/suF7b/2/)**

Comment: was this a bubbling problem? is that why you're attaching to the body?

Comment: @Deviland, I think it is bubbling problem

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this several times recently. If you bind the event to the new table row as you are doing, it won't work. The reason is that the rows don't exist at the time you do the binding. You *could* use `live`, but I think it is being [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in favor of the following style.

You can use `on` to bind it to the table like this:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.newtb', function (event) {
    //Do stuff
});
```

This sets the event on the table, which already exists in the DOM at the time of the binding.

Hope that makes sense....

Comment: Don't mind the downvote, but a comment on why might help me avoid whatever caused it in the future... is my information wrong?

Comment: if you ever got a -1 for this, i dont know why!. +1 from me, I dont want to hook it up to the body.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following update in your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/suF7b/8/

You need to make that event binding every time you add new code.

```
$('#mytable').append(newRow);
captureEvent();

function captureEvent() {
    // capture click of new row?
    $('.newtb').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();  
        alert('clicked');
    });
}
```

Comment: this works for only the last added item the current added item does not fire (added two new rows first works second does not?)

Answer (score 0):

Use Event delegation ... **[=> FIDDLE HERE <=](http://jsfiddle.net/qBBdc/)**

// To me, detecting the target element "by hand" is the best way !

// because you can fully handle the way you detect clicked elements ...

```
$('#mytable').on('click', function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target), $tr = $target.closest('tr');
    if($tr.length)){
      //  $tr.get(0) is the clicked TR element
      alert($tr.get(0).nodeName+' clicked !'+"\n"+e.target.nodeName+' the actual clicked element');
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
});
```

-
*Alternative to deprecated "live" method : use "on" method with delegation signature instead*

```
$('#mytable').on('click', 'tr', function(event){
    // don't know if any element inside the tr will be caught while clicking on it
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at this jsfiddle:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/suF7b/5/)

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td><input type="textbox" class="mytb"/></td>
    <td><button id="addButton">Add New Row</button></td>     
</tr>
</table>​

$(document).ready(function(){

// generate new row
$('#addButton').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();                 
  var newRow = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="newtb"/></td></tr>';
  $('#mytable').append(newRow);        
});

// capture click of new row?
$('.newtb').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  
    alert('clicked');
});
});
```

Comment: 'live' method is deprecated as of 1.7, use 'on' method with delegation signature instead...

Comment: live is deprecated so I would prefer not to use it

Comment: ... how come your code is exactly the same as the OP's...? Are you editing right now or something?