# dynamic remove row wont work, only removes first row and not others

Tags: jquery

When i try to remove the first row it works but as i add more rows i cant delete them. For some reason i can only remove the first row.

here is my html

```
<table class="pretty property_units" style="width:800px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Bedroom</th>
<th>Bathroom</th>
<th>Square Feet</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Available</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="rows">
    <td><input type='text' name='bedroom[]' value='0' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='bath[]' value='0' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='sqrt[]' value='0' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='price[]' value='0' class='input-small'></td>
    <td>
        <select name='avail[]' class='input-small'>
        <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
        <option value='no'>No</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-small removeRow">remove</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-primary addrow">add row</button>
```

here is my js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".addrow").click(function() {
        var tblrow = $('table.property_units tr.rows:last').clone();
        $("table.property_units tbody").append(tblrow);
    });

    $(".removeRow").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery how to bind onclick event to dynamically added HTML element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element)

Comment: i've seen the sample that you listed but it wasnt very clear. My sample is very clear to the reader, very clear and clean code.

Comment: If that question wasn't clear to you, maybe one of the many questions it's linked to would be. This question is asked on a daily basis on SO, one of them should have an answer that you understand.

Comment: hopefully this one will help another person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delegate the event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeRow', function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    return false;
});
```

To improve performance, I would add an id to the table and bind the event to the table instead of `document`.

For further explanation [have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8110934/983992).

Comment: thanks for your answer, so with $(document) instead of $('.removeRow') it waits for an event to take place?

Comment: also what is the difference between $().click and $().on('click')

Comment: It basically adds the click event to `document` and checks if the actual clicked element was the one with `.removeRow`. If you bind it directly to `.removeRow`, newly created elements will not have any event handler. `click` is just the short version of `on('click')` but `on` allows you to add a delegate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you create new element with jQuery you must bind a event. You can use delegate instead click, check here:
[enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

or you can make function deleteRws(){ your code for delete}
and then call it after :
$("table.property_units tbody").append(tblrow);

Answer (score 0):

That `$(".removeRow").click(...` only applies to any matching rows that existed at the time it was called. It won't affect new rows (and their contents) created via your `.addrow` click handler.

You'll need to add that manually:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var remover = function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    return false;
  };

  $(".addrow").click(function() {
          var tblrow = $('table.property_units tr.rows:last').clone();
          $('.removeRow', tblrow).click(remover);
          $("table.property_units tbody").append(tblrow);
      });

  $(".removeRow").click(remover);
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/Bekit

Comment: i never knew you can do this,  $('.removeRow', tblrow)