# JQuery bind() method not working

Tags: jquery, bind

I make some code like this
Ajax give me a pagination bar with the `<a href="" class="page-navi page--4">4</a>` for example.
But bind and alert not working. Why?

```
    <script ... >
$(function() {
  $(".page-navi").bind("click",function() {
alert("!!!");
});
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "some url",
        type: "GET",
        success:function(data, status, jqxhr)
        {
            $("#pagination").html(data);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }                        
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery how to bind onclick event to dynamically added HTML element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling an ajax method to update your #pagination element immediately after loading.

If your .page-navi element is inside this #pagination element the event handler you attached via bind will be wiped out.

Move to inside the ajax success.

Answer (score -1):

I test your code and works correctly without AJAX call. BIND is an old event handler, I suggest you to use ON. Just replace BIND with ON. The reason is that you are trying to attach event before the DOM elements would be loaded. I think my suggestion will help you.