# Remove element after append

Tags: jquery

Does anyone knows why I cannot remove the letter B in the list?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. click on "Add to list" button
2. letter B is added to the list
3. click on letter B in the list to remove
4. letter B is not removed from list
5. click on letter C or A
6. letter C or A is removed from list

**HTML:**

```
<button id="add">Add to list</button>
<ol>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>A</li>
</ol>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ol").append("<li>C</li");

    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("ol").append("<li>B</li>");
    });

    $("li").on("click",function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Here you have the sample in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsh4pb5r/1/).

Best regards.

Comment: I checked in chrome and it is working on double click

Comment: I've tried again and it only works for letter A and C, for B still not removing even changing the click to dblclick.

Comment: [example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phutis/qsh4pb5r/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamic item

Try like this

```
$(document).on("click","li",function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qsh4pb5r/3/)

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the event handler is lost when you append a new element. You can refer to the solution in the following answer to see how to do it correctly.
[jQuery how to bind onclick event to dynamically added HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element)

```
Here is your JSFiddle
 https://jsfiddle.net/qsh4pb5r/1/
```