# Can't select added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I faced this problem while doing some exercises. Can't select recently added button number two, and cant call alert method

```
$('#but').click(function() {
  $('#but').after('<button id="but2">Кнопка 2</button');
});
$('#but2').click(function() {
  alert('something');
});
```

Having only this HTML code:

```
<button id="but">Кнопка 1</button>
```

Comment: You should use event delegation for dynamically added elements

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element

Answer (score 1):

Your `htmlString` is lacking a `>` on its closing tag:

```
.after('<button id="but2">Кнопка 2</button');
                                          ^
```

And use event delegation for dynamic elements:

```
$(document).on('click','#but2',function(){
   alert('something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have dynamically added button. And direct click event will not work.

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#but2',function(){
   alert('something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to select the second button

```
$('#but').eq(2).click(function() {
  alert('something');
});
```