# Jquery handler called only once

Tags: jquery

I need to do something when I click on the grid `pager`.

This is the `HTML` where the pager is. The `css` class is `dxp-num`
 [image]

I have added this code in the `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dxp-num").click(function () {
        alert("The pager was clicked.");
    });
});
```

I have tried to add the same code outside the `document.ready.`
the alert is showing only once in both examples. I need to enter on that click event every time I click on a page number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery how to bind onclick event to dynamically added HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element)

Comment: What does `aspxGVPagerOnClick` do?

Comment: You want a `delegated event handler`. See `.on`. `$(".dxpLite_Office2003Olive").on('click', .dxp-num, function() {})`.

Comment: something like `$('body').on("click",".dxp-num",function(){.............});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinks your page elements are added dynamically. If it is so, use jquery `on` rather than binding `click` to the element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".dxp-num", function () {
        alert("The pager was clicked.");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#gvPartners_DXPagerBottom").on("click", ".dxp-num", function () {
        alert("The pager was clicked.");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you added those element dinamically (after DOM creation, via javascript) then they won't respond to a bind created earlier than their creation. You need [delegated event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation). That means: a parent (not created dinamically) will recieve the event and pass it to their childs:

```
$(".dxpLite_Office2003Olive").on("click", ".dxp-num", function() {
    alert("The pager was clicked.");
});
```

or

```
$("#gvPartners_DXPagerBottom").on("click", ".dxp-num", function() {
    alert("The pager was clicked.");
});
```

you can use ANY parent, no matter how far, as long as it's been created before:

```
$("body").on("click", ".dxp-num", function() {
    alert("The pager was clicked.");
});
```