# can not access on click function of a css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this

```
  <form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="AddComment" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" id="CommentForm">
     <div class=" w-100 mt-1  ml-5 mr-5  d-block">
        <div class="d-inline-block">
           <lable class="product-subtitle">Name</lable>
            <input id="Name" type="text" class="reply-comment" value="@fullname" disabled />
         </div>
         <div class="d-inline-block ">
              <lable class="product-subtitle">Email</lable>
                 <input id="Email" type="email" class="reply-comment" value="@userEmail" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-1  ml-5 mr-5 d-block ">
         <textarea rows="3" class="reply-comment" id="Comment" name="Comment"></textarea>
        </div>
         <div class="mt-1  ml-5 mr-5 mb-4 d-flex  justify-content-end">
            <div>
              <a class="btn btn-primary btn-buy d-flex justify-content-center add-comment" data-id="0"  data-ischild="0" style=" background-color: #425fab;width:80px; padding:10px"><span>Send</span></a>
             </div>
          </div>
     </form>
```

and js

```
 $(".add-comment").click(function () {
    //some thing happens in here

});
```

this works fine. and I can access .add-comment.click() function , but in somepart I have to add the textarea by javascript like this

```
let divStr = "<div class='w-75 d-inline-flex'><textarea id='ChildComment' class='reply-comment w-100' ></textarea></div>";
    divStr = divStr + "<div class='w-25 d-inline-flex align-bottom' style='float:left; justify-content:left;'>";        
     divStr = divStr + "<a  class='btn btn-buy d-inline add-comment' data-id='" + commentId +"' data-ischild='1'><span class='mr-1 ml-1'> Send</span></a></div>";
      $("#" + commentId).append(divStr);
```

but the I can not enter .add-comment.click(function()) when I make the textarea by javascript

Comment: we need a working example / link to help you out here mate

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525664/jquery-how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element) should help you (use the on method).

Comment: you can also use this code as well, 
$('body').on('click', '.add-comment', function() {
    //some thing happens in here
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
 $(".add-comment").click(function () {
    //some thing happens in here

});
```

into this

```
 $(document).on('click', '.add-comment', function() {
    //some thing happens in here

});
```

The first one doesn't work because the item is added after the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you're trying to attach a click event onto an element that has been dynamically added. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.reply-comment',function(){//do something})
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but taking the wording as-is "*trying to attach a click event onto an element that has been dynamically added*" - is not a problem as you *can* attach events to elements that *have been* added - ie added dynamically then event added after.  The issue is the event is being added *before* the element has been added/exists.  I suspect that's what you're trying to say, but as-is, it's not worded to be factually correct.